# Field not used warning in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm implementing a login filter in a JSF application. I have a private field called config. Eclipse displays a warning "The value of the field AuthenticationFilter.config is not used" despite the field being referred to in the init and destroy methods. Am I doing something wrong here or is Eclipse a bit confused?

Here's the AuthenticationFilter class:

```
package com.mymato.coop;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter("/restricted/*")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

      private FilterConfig config;

      public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
          FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession().getAttribute(
            LoginBean.AUTH_KEY) == null) {
          ((HttpServletResponse) resp).sendRedirect("../login.xhtml");
        } else {
          chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }
      }

      public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        this.config = config;
      }

      public void destroy() {
        config = null;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialising and destroying `config` aren't "using" them - the compiler is telling you that you've got a variable that you're wasting memory and time initialising and destroying when it isn't being used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using a field is not giving a value to it.
In your code, you give a value to the field but you never use this field.

In your case, if your field has a value but that this valued field is never used as input value in another instruction, it seems to be useless. The field has a value but nobody uses this value. 
So, why declaring it ? Whereas, the warning.

In your code `config` is never used. why declaring it ? 
Maybe, your class build is in progress and you will need it.
Maybe, you never need to store the`config` object to use it later. So you can remove the field in your class. 
Question yourself about it .

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just assign it to null will solve your problem

```
private FilterConfig config = null;
```

Sometimes I have this problem too. I think it's the because of the way FilterConfig class is implemented.

Although since you assign the pointer to another one, I don't see why there is a problem. Another quick fix: put some getters/setters, even though you might not use them :D

**UPDATE**: Also, what *davidhxxx* said